# Listing down stored records EncryptedLocalStore - Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, air

How do I get to list down the stored records in the EncryptedLocalStore for loop? Of course I'm talking about javascript and Adobe Air.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve the list of stored items from an ELS using JavaScript or for that matter Adobe AIR. As per the API, 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

ELS supports only working with known keys. There is no way to get a list of keys from the ELS, this is to prevent circumventing the security around ELS - which is the prime objective of the functionality.

If you want to do the same in your own application, extend ELS and make sure you keep storing keys passed to ELS in a separate database table/shared object, which may query later to get a list of all keys.